# jQuery event handling with foreign function

Tags: jquery

I would like to run a simple script, which adds `html` element into `div`.

I want to call this function more times, so I used `this` keyword.

My code is:

```
function insert(element, html) {
    $( html ).appendTo( element );
}

$('#div').bind('click', insert(this,'<p>inserted text</p>'));
```

Dunno whats wrong, thank you.

Comment: You are calling `insert` and try to bind the return value (`undefined`) as event handler. You have to pass a function to `bind` instead. Only inside that function (i.e. the event handler), `this` will refer to the clicked element. Please read http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-basics/.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery `bind` expects the second parameter to be a `function`, but you're passing the **returned value** of the `insert` function (which is `undefined` in your case, since it doesn't return anything).

What you actually want is:

```
function insert(element, html)
      {
      $( html ).appendTo( element );
      }

$('#div').bind('click', function() { insert(this,'<p>inserted text</p>'); });
```

Or:

```
function insert(html)
      {
      return function() { $(html).appendTo(this); };
      }

$('#div').bind('click', insert('<p>inserted text</p>'));
```

Comment: Im sorry, im newb in jQuery, but when i run this script in firebug it shows 0 errors.

Answer (score 0):

`$( html ).appendTo( $(element) );`

Comment: No. The argument passed to `.appendTo` can be a DOM element. It does not have to be a jQuery object. Your "solution" will be equivalent to what the OP already has.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're not passing a callback function to `bind`, you're passing the *result* of *calling that function*. Clearly, that's not what you're trying to achieve here and it's a common mistake for beginning jQuery developers. It's so common that they even put it into the [jQuery Basics](http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/) (see *Callbacks and Functions > Callback with Arguments*). That's a recommended read, by the way.

You need to pass a *function* which calls `insert(this,'<p>inserted text</p>');` when it is executed. Thus, that would look like:

```
$('#div').bind('click', function() {
    insert(this, '<p>inserted text</p>');
});
```

Event handlers are bound to the affected DOM element for their `this` context, and I believe that's what you're trying to do here. If not, you'll need to "fix" the `this` context of your event handler using some trickery (e.g. `Function.prototype.bind` or `jQuery.proxy`).